# Java getMethod() not finding method

Tags: java, reflection, methods

I'm trying to work with Java's reflections to create a module loader for a project, but the getMethod() method seems to refuse to locate the method that exists, even when the method is clearly defined.

In the Module.class file:
`public final void load(org.clustermc.core.ClusterCore plugin);`

I asked the core to print out the methods it finds within the Class. The result:
`Methods: [public void me.capit.clustersample.SampleModule.onLoad(), public void me.capit.clusterSample.SampleModule.onUnload(), public final void org.clustermc.core.Module.load(org.clustermc.core.ClusterCore), /*Other stuff from Object*/];`
Note that the SampleModule extends Module.

Over in the core:
`Method enable = c.getMethod("onLoad");
Method init = c.getMethod("load", org.clustermc.core.ClusterCore.class);`

The 'enable' variable for onLoad() works just fine, but the upon trying to find load(ClusterCore.class), I get a NoSuchMethodException. Why...?

Comment: If you are working with multiple `ClassLoader`s, make sure you don’t load classes multiple times through different loaders. Otherwise you may encounter the problem that `ClusterCore.class` refers to a different runtime class than the `ClusterCore` parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scope of load method, if it is private then it will not be accessed. You need to set acessible true. Notice the getDeclaredMethod instead of getMethod.

```
Method init = c.getDeclaredMethod("load", org.clustermc.core.ClusterCore.class);
```

Before invoking you need to execute this line :-

```
 init.setAccessible(true);
```